# Payment method for penalty

Tags: paypal, payment

I need to implement a penalty system, where if a user does not do any job then he needs to pay some penalty. Which payment method should we use to get it collected automatically, without forcing them to pay. Can we use paypal,. Which paypal api will suit my requirement. I cannot ask user for their api credentials so is there any workaround so that I can charge them

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're wanting to do.  You want to be able to take a payment from them...but not force them to pay..??  What does that mean?

Comment: I mean payment to be automatically deducted from their cc or paypal

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled in a couple of different ways.

First, you can use [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) with [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/) and/or [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#wpp).

Alternatively, you could use the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/) API to setup [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/) Profiles for use with the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API.